# Firebase Storage - Download URL different from actual Download URL in the console (token differs)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Most of the time I get the download URL of the file uploaded correct after successfully uploading the file and able to retrieve the file back, but few times the token of the download URL is incorrect after successfully uploading the file and unable to retrieve the file. When I checked the Firebase Console, the token in the download URL is different.

Comment: Can you further share the details of the problem?

Comment: I am using firebase storage for uploading my images from app.The download url that we get .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

Comment: Okay, What is wrong with the URL? What is the correct URL and what is the wrong URL?

Comment: i use glide to load the image from the url  and following error is obtained java.io.IOException: Request failed 403: Forbidden when i check the download url of the image from the firebase storage console their is a difference in token between the two.

Comment: It is actually a bug in the Firebase, I am also faced the same problem, this error does not occur all the time but some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download URLs are invalidated in two ways:

- The download URL is deleted in the Firebase Console
- A new object is uploaded (which effectively deletes the object, and thus the token should expire)

It sounds like you might be hitting the second case--if so, this is intended behavior (since you're retrieving a different file), so you should make sure to take the URL you retrieved after upload (we return it in the metadata after upload) and store it appropriately. Glide is likely caching the old URL which is why it's failing (you'll need to invalidate the cache if the file changes).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Retrieving url after successful upload  eg : addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() { @Override public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();} .If the open the same url using web browser similar error (403) is shown.